# Chronometer stopwatch: Time keeps increasing in background when stop is pushed

Tags: android, chronometer

When I press the stop button it stops the time from being viewed but still increments in the background. When I press start it shows the entire time that it was stopped. Does anyone know how to make stop actually stop?

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;

public class StopwatchFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {


    public StopwatchFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    Button startChron;
    Button stopChron;
    Button resetChron;
    private Chronometer chron;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stopwatch_main, container, false);
        getActivity().getActionBar()
                .setTitle("Stopwatch");
        startChron = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.start);
               startChron.setOnClickListener(this);
        stopChron = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.stop);
               stopChron.setOnClickListener(this);
        resetChron = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.reset);
               resetChron.setOnClickListener(this);
        chron = (Chronometer) v.findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
        return v;


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == startChron){
            chron.start();
        }
        else if (v == stopChron){
            chron.stop();
        }
        else if (v == resetChron){
            chron.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "but still increments in the background" - how do you know that ?

Comment: @ShadabAnsari say I press start it goes to 5 seconds and I press stop and I leave it stopped for 3 seconds. When I press start the timer automatically updates to 8 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to save in a variable the time when the chrono is paused. Something like this:

```
difference = chron.getBase() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
```

And then to set the time when resume:

```
time = timeDifference + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
```

Comment: But I'm not trying to fully reset the clock. I just want it to pick up where it left off. I called chron.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()); in the reset function

Comment: @user2980816 I edited the answer based in your comment.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is because calling `stop()` doesn't changes your `Chronometer` base as set using `setBase()`. If you want to make your `Chronometer` start afresh, then everytime you call `start()` you need to `setBase()` before it.

```
chron.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
```

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html#stop()).

Comment: But I'm not trying to fully reset the clock. I just want it to pick up where it left off. I called chron.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()); in the reset function

Comment: You have to setBase() before start().